# Could you explain this information?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

See this [site](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-clauses.html):

> 2: We can't use this kind of participle clause if we're talking about one finished action which is not repeated:
>
> - Not: <s>Who was the girl dropping the coffee?</s>
>
> Instead, we use a normal relative clause:
>
> - Who was the girl who dropped the coffee?

Could you explain "**We can't use this kind of participle clause if we're talking about one finished action which is not repeated**"?

What does "**one finished action which is not repeated**" mean?

There is no way to understand what the author was talking about.

Comment: Do you understand what a _participle clause_ and a _relative clause_ are?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Of course, I do

Comment: @P.E.Dant, what does "one finished action which is not repeated" mean?

Comment: Do you see a participle clause in first sentence? The action of dropping the coffee is completed, so we use the relative clause as in the second sentence. What about this do you not understand? She doesn't go on spilling coffee until the end of time. She is finished with spilling coffee (for now, at least) so we use _dropped_ and not _dropping._

Comment: "is not repeated" mean?

Comment: Does your dictionary define the verb _repeat?_ How about the adjective _repeated?_ (You can understand this without anyone's assistance if you use your dictionary and think for a moment. It is not difficult!)

Comment: @Tom: She dropped the coffee. That action is finished and done. She will not drop the coffee again. The action of dropping the coffee is not repeated. If I said "Who was the girl making the coffee", a girl making one coffee is quite likely to make coffee again.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous is used with actions that recur (actions that "repeat") or with actions that take some time to run their course.

> What's your son Joe doing this summer to earn money?
>   --He's *delivering* The Evening Bulletin.
>
> The faucet was *dripping*.
>
> She was *singing* the national anthem when it began to rain cats and
>   dogs.

Joe does not deliver newspapers around the clock. He delivers them *daily*.

The faucet was not running continuously. It was going drip-drip-drip. The action recurs.

Singing is continuous. The song starts and goes until it's over.

> The tea kettle was whistling.

In the original example quoted, a girl spills her coffee. When we spill coffee, it's normally an instantaneous thing. The cup gets knocked over.  But if she were slowly pouring out her coffee into someone's lap, then we could say "the girl who was spilling her coffee..."